# How to write output of a command to multiple files without displaying on screen

Tags: shell, io-redirection

Here in the example is date command.

I have tried

```
date &> file file2 file3
```

does not work

```
date | tee file file2 file3
```

works but also displays on the console

Is there a way if I can run date command and it displays output to multiple files and not on the terminal.

Comment: You may try `date | tee file file2 >file3` or `date | tee file file2 file3 >/dev/null` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Use `tee`, but redirect the "final" stdout to `/dev/null`:

```
date | tee file file2 file3 >/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `zsh`, this construct works:

```
date > file1 > file2 > file3
```

If running in `bash`, only `file3` will contain the output.

Comment: I believe this is `zsh`-specific.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for the info!